# Display text as it is entered

Tags: javascript

I have a simple `<input type="text">` field in my html code with `onChange` property set to call javascript function, which takes the text and displays it. So, how it looks like currently:

```
<input type="text" id="inputField" onChange="displayText()"></input>    
<span id="toDisplay"></span>
```

and javascript:

```
function displayText() {
 var text = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
 document.getElementById("toDisplay").innerHTML = text;
}
```

So the text in the span is updated when the user presses enter.

Is there a way of doing a "real-time" update? In other words, I would like the text to appear in the span as soon as the user enters it.

Comment: Try `onkeypress` or `onkeyup` events

Comment: Use `onkeyup` to get the value of the input and send it to the span.

Comment: If you don't have any problem in using a framework, then you can use Angular.js. It has a built in feature of binding the data. I have created a fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linux_nerd/zGGWY/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="inputField" onKeyUp="displayText()"></input>
```